# Limiting findall() in beautifulsoup to just a section of the html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Here is my situation, i am scraping this html fine with this code but i dont find how to separate the first section from the second. i just want to scrape the first section and apart the second section. using beautifulsoup4

- *dont mind myData(link), is the urlopen and html read function.*

**The html**

```
<div id="first_content" class="header">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="row">
            <a name="03049302"></a>
            <div class="col-xs-12 drop-panel-content">
                <p>
                    first section first text. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="drop-panel drop-panel-one-row-height">
                <p class="text-center">Edit</p>
                <p class="text-center">Share</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <a name="03049303"></a>
            <div class="col-xs-12 drop-panel-content">
                <p>

                    first section second text. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="drop-panel drop-panel-one-row-height">
                <p class="text-center">Edit</p>
                <p class="text-center">Share</p>
                <section id="second_content">
                    <a name="aname" class="btn-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#aname">
                        <h3>A Name</h3>
                    </a>
                    <div class="collapse flush-width flush-down" id="aname">
                        <div class="list">
                            <div class="row">
                                <a name="03049304"></a>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 drop-panel-content">
                                    <p>

                                        second section first text. </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="drop-panel drop-panel-one-row-height">
                                    <p class="text-center">Edit</p>
                                    <p class="text-center">Share</p>
                              </div>
```

**This is the code:**

```
try:
    all_data = myData(link).findAll("div", {"class": "col-xs-12 drop-panel-content"})
    for data in all_data:
        print data.text

except AttributeError as e:
    return None
```

**Apart as in not in the same output

**Current output**

```
first section first text.
first section second text.
second section first text.
```

**Wanted output**

```
first section first text.
first section second text.
```

**and wanted output, apart in another function maybe**

```
second section first text.
```

Comment: So what is your expected output? `"first section first text."`? What does it mean `and apart the second one`?

Comment: just fix and add my expected output to the question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to differentiate the sections using that `section` tag. The second section is inside the `section` tag, but the first one is not.

```
all_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col-xs-12 drop-panel-content"})
for data in all_data:
    if data.find_parent("section") is None:
        print data.get_text(strip=True)
```

Or, if there are strictly 2 first section texts, simply slice the list of section texts:

```
all_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col-xs-12 drop-panel-content"})[:2]
for data in all_data:
    print data.get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: dammn, I fix a lot just with this `strip=True`

Comment: differentiating the section did the trick, because there are more than 2 text, that was just an example, thanks a lot !!!!!!!